# Header tag appearing on top of another element partially hidden

Tags: css

I'm trying to get my header tag to appear at the top of my page but above the main div tag (has a class of wrapper). The header tag is coded above the wrapper div in the html file as seen below. My header tag is mostly covered by the background image because I set the background of the header to white but since the background is black it hides portions of the header tag. Please help. Thank you.

```
<body>
    <header>
    <ul>
          <li><a>Home</a></li>
          <li><a>About</a></li>
          <li><a>Contact</a></li>
          <li><a>Links</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Link 1</li>
                <li>Link 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="upload-console">
        <h2 class="upload-console-header">Upload</h2>

        <div class="upload-console-body">
          <h3>Select files</h3>
          <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" id="standard-upload-files" multiple>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload files" id="standard-upload">
          </form>

          <h3>Or drag and drop files below</h3>
          <div class="upload-console-drop" id="drop-zone">
            Just drag and drop files here
          </div>

          <div class="bar">
            <div class="bar-fill" id="bar-fill">
              <div class="bar-fill-text" id="bar-fill-text"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="uploads-finished" class="hidden">
            <h3>Processed Files</h3>
            <!--<div class="upload-console-upload">
              <a href="">filename.zip</a>
              <span>Success</span>
            </div>-->
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="global.js"></script>
  <body>
```

Here is link to what the page is looking like. 
https://www.z1labs.com/fts.html

All of the css can be seen here: 
https://www.z1labs.com/global.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header can't be seen because it has no height. It contains unordered lists with no height set and the `li` elements have `float: left;` so they aren't included in the height calculation.

Either look into using a clearfix or try flex or some other layout to combat the float.